# Recommended location of node.js applications in linux filesystem?

Tags: directory-structure, node.js

Where is the conventionally accepted location of node.js/express web apps, in a linux file system?

Currently I've got a subdirectory in `/opt/` but I'd like to hear other people's view on this...

Answer (score 15):

The `/opt` directory is a good location for the program *distribution* files. The `/srv` directory is used for the programs run-time *data*. (Please see the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).) Unlike the `/etc` directory where the standard indicates that the `/opt/<pkg>` configuration files should be placed in `/etc/opt/<pkg>`, there is no standardization that `/srv/opt/<pkg>` should be a parallel structure (although it's probably not a bad idea).

In summary:

```
/opt/webserver/     (your node.js application)
    server.js
    package.json
    node_modules/
    ...

/etc/opt/webserver/
    config.json     (configuration file for your web server)

/srv/opt/webserver/ (opt subdirectory suggested, but not required)
    index.html
    images/
    css/
    ...

/var/opt/webserver
    error.log
    request.log
```

Please keep in mind that this is the general case, and is not unique to express applicaitons.

Comment: Why did you recommend to put logs into `/var/opt/webserver` and not into `/var/log/webserver`? Is this a typo?

Comment: On a Google Compute Engine running Debian should /opt or /srv directory be good enough to deploy a node application so the multiple users can access it with read/write permissions?

Comment: What are the best permissions for the opt folder?

Answer (score 5):

The most appropriate place would be under [`/srv`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM).